# Keep md-select open until clicked outside - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, md-select

I am using md-select rendering md-checkbox wiyth a selectAll option.

If I select all, all checkboxes are selected and the dropdown closes which is expected.

How do I trigger not to close the dropdown when any value other than All is selected and close it on outside click?

```js
var app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

app.controller('mdSelectController', function($scope, $mdPanel, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog) {

  $scope.helpers = [{
      name: 'All',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Ron',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Jim',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Paul',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Jeremie',
      selected: false
    }
  ];

  $scope.changeCheckbox = function(rating) {
  console.log(rating)
    if (rating.name === 'All' && rating.selected === true) {
      _.forEach($scope.helpers, function(item) {
        item.selected = true;
      });
    }
    if (rating.name === 'All' && rating.selected === false) {
      _.forEach($scope.helpers, function(item) {
        item.selected = false;
      });
    }
    if (rating.name !== 'All') {
      console.log("Not all");
      _.forEach($scope.helpers, function(item) {
        if (item.name === 'All') {
          item.selected = false;
        }
      });
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-controller="mdSelectController" ng-cloak>
  <!--
    Your HTML content here
  -->

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js">
  </script>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Rating</label>
    <md-select id="ratingDropdown" ng-model="automationRatingObj" md-container-class="ratingDropdown" required="required">
      <md-option ng-value="rating" ng-repeat="rating in helpers track by $index">
        <md-checkbox ng-model="rating.selected" aria-label="Select a Rating" ng-change="changeCheckbox(rating)"></md-checkbox>{{rating.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>

</body>

</html>
```

Please advice. I checked the API of md-select but they dont have any code to keep the dropdown open. Also, how do I disable click on the text inside md-select and enable click only for checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the dropdown to  close when clicking all, but to remain open when clicking any other item. You can check for which value you are at in ng-repeat and add $event.stopPropagation(); to all objects without 'All'. You can do this using ternary operator on ng-click on md-option: ng-click="rating.name != 'All' ? $event.stopPropagation(): ''"

```js
var app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

app.controller('mdSelectController', function($scope, $mdPanel, $mdSidenav, $mdDialog) {

  $scope.helpers = [{
      name: 'All',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Ron',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Jim',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Paul',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Jeremie',
      selected: false
    }
  ];

  $scope.changeCheckbox = function(rating) {
  console.log(rating)
    if (rating.name === 'All' && rating.selected === true) {
      _.forEach($scope.helpers, function(item) {
        item.selected = true;
      });
    }
    if (rating.name === 'All' && rating.selected === false) {
      _.forEach($scope.helpers, function(item) {
        item.selected = false;
      });
    }
    if (rating.name !== 'All') {
      console.log("Not all");
      _.forEach($scope.helpers, function(item) {
        if (item.name === 'All') {
          item.selected = false;
        }
      });
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-controller="mdSelectController" ng-cloak>
  <!--
    Your HTML content here
  -->

  <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js">
  </script>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Rating</label>
    <md-select id="ratingDropdown" ng-model="automationRatingObj" md-container-class="ratingDropdown" required="required">
      <md-option ng-value="rating" ng-repeat="rating in helpers track by $index" ng-click="rating.name != 'All' ? $event.stopPropagation(): ''" >
        <md-checkbox ng-model="rating.selected" aria-label="Select a Rating" ng-change="changeCheckbox(rating)"></md-checkbox>{{rating.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One small question: Is there a way I can disable click on the text and only enable click on the checkbox?

Comment: @a2441918  you could change the ng-click on md-option to just "$event.stopPropagation()" then add the ternary operator "rating.name != 'All' ? $event.stopPropagation(): ''" to the md-checkbox element. This will prevent click actions on anything except the checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiple` from `md-select` instead of using `md-checkbox`.
But you need update `changeCheckbox` function - for select `ALL`.

Something like this:

```
<md-select id="ratingDropdown" ng-model="automationRatingObj" md-container-class="ratingDropdown" required="required" multiple="true" ng-change="changeCheckbox()">
      <md-option ng-value="rating" ng-repeat="rating in helpers track by $index" >
        {{rating.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
```

Comment: I did that, but I am not able to access the checkbox selected property.

Comment: add to function `changeCheckbox` - `console.log($scope. automationRatingObj)`

Comment: that contains selected items - you can check this array and mark entity.